# error message of java.net.UnknownHostException for nutch 2.3

Tags: nutch

I am trying to crawl web data using nutch 2.3 on Linux Mint 17.2, but get the following error message
“Failed with the following error: java.net.UnknownHostException:”
I'd like to know what causes this error and how to resolve it. My observation is that this error sometimes comes with another error message "Couldn't get robots.txt."  What are the relationships between these two errors and how to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this happens when Nutch can't resolve a given URL, does this happens with specific URLs? or when you run some specific Nutch commands?